# What's the point of declare-styleable?

Tags: android, attr, android-custom-view, android-resources, declare-styleable

Suppose I am making some new views with styleable attributes. I declare them thusly (this is [how the documentation says to do it](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="TriangleView">
        <attr name="direction">
            <enum name="NE" value="0" />
            <enum name="NW" value="1" />
            <enum name="SW" value="2" />
            <enum name="SE" value="3" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="BannerView">
        <attr name="direction">
            <enum name="NE" value="0" />
            <enum name="NW" value="1" />
            <enum name="SW" value="2" />
            <enum name="SE" value="3" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="thickness" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

However, this won't work because all attributes are apparently in the same namespace, and I get the error `Error: Attribute "direction" has already been defined`.

So apparently I have to move the apparently duplicated attributes outside the `<declare-styleable>` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


    <attr name="direction">
        <enum name="NE" value="0" />
        <enum name="NW" value="1" />
        <enum name="SW" value="2" />
        <enum name="SE" value="3" />
    </attr>

    <declare-styleable name="BannerView">
        <attr name="thickness" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

But this poses two questions:

1. If this works, what exactly is the point of `<declare-styleable>`?
2. What if I want the attribute to behave differently in different views? For example if `BannerView`'s direction can only be `up` or `down`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What exactly is the point of `<declare-styleable>`?

`<declare-stylable>` tags let you declare attributes for your custom views that you can then set for those views in xml.  There are really 3 parts to using the attribute:

1. Declare an `<attr>` inside of a `<declare-stylable>` tag.
2. Define a custom namespace in your xml layout pointing to your app package name (ex. `app`). Use the custom attribute in your layout (ex. `app:direction="NW"`).
3. In your custom view, override the constructors with an `AttributeSet` parameter, get a `TypedArray` and read the custom attributes, if any, from it and then within the constructor tell the view how to use those attributes appropriately.

> What if I want the attribute to behave differently in different views?
>   For example if BannerView's direction can only be up or down.

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <attr name="direction">
        <enum name="NE" value="0" />
        <enum name="NW" value="1" />
        <enum name="SW" value="2" />
        <enum name="SE" value="3" />
    </attr>

    <declare-styleable name="TriangleView">
        <attr name="direction" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="BannerView">
        <attr name="direction" />
        <attr name="thickness" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

When you build your xml layout for `TriangleView` or `BannerView`, you can use the `app:direction="NW"` example for both.  In the constructors with `AttributeSet` in `TriangleView` or `BannerView`, the attributes will have the same format as the original, but what you ***do*** with that value is dependent on your implementation of the constructors in each respective view (can be the same or different for both).

If you want attributes to be ***defined*** differenly (ie. different "format" or "enum") for different views, then you have to create different attributes with different names.

Comment: Awesome, actually helped me as well for attr defined in the app-compat lib! So it's basically, if an attr is already defined, it should be used in the declare-styleable, without trying to override the format. Cool cool cool.

Comment: But in layout gradle insists you use 'xmlns:XXX="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"' for declaring namespace so even if you use for instance two namespaces: 'xmlns:XXX" and 'xmlns:XXY"  and have attributes with <declare-styleable name="XXX"> and <declare-styleable name="XXY"> and declare attributes for a view in a layout file as XXX:a=..." and XXY:a="..." you have a namespace clash and get a "Duplicate resources" error.  Why?